# In .NET Core, libMan install 'Failed to download resource'

Tags: .net-framework

I am working with .NET core in Ubuntu 18.04 behind a proxy server. When I try to install a library using 'libMan' utility (**version** 1.0.172+g2a33cb3eeb) got ''Failed to download resource' error message.

**Tried command:** 
libman install @aspnet/signalr -p unpkg -d wwwroot/lib/signalr --files dist/browser/signalr.js --files dist/browser/signalr.min.js

**Error message:** 
Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Contracts.ResourceDownloadException: Failed to download resource from "https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=signalr+scope:aspnet"
   at Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.WebRequestHandler.GetStreamAsync(String url, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Extensions.GetJsonObjectViaGetAsync(IWebRequestHandler webRequestHandler, String url, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Providers.Unpkg.NpmPackageSearch.GetPackageNamesWithScopeAsync(String searchTerm, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Providers.Unpkg.NpmPackageSearch.GetPackageNamesAsync(String searchTerm, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Providers.Unpkg.UnpkgCatalog.SearchAsync(String term, Int32 maxHits, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[LIB002]: The "@aspnet/signalr" library could not be resolved by the "unpkg" provider

**Apparently present version of libman utility does not offer 'config' command for configuring proxy settings. Does anyone know a workaround to this proxy issue?**

**Edited**:

New version of  **libman utility** is out that supports 'config' command for configuring proxy settings

Comment: "I am working with .NET core" - Please provide more details than this. What version of .NET Core are you using?

Comment: dotnet --version 2.2.203

Comment: New version of  **libman utility** is out that supports 'config' command for configuring proxy settings